# s-files generated from riscv-gnu-toolchain does not run RISCV emulator

Tags: c++, assembly, gnu-toolchain, riscv32

I must compile a set of C++ files into RISC-V code (RV32IM). I am using *riscv-gnu-toolchain* and compiles with the following CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)
project(project-title)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-march=rv32im -mabi=ilp32 --save-temps")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER riscv32-unknown-elf-g++)
```

If I input a test C++ file, like the following

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
}
```

then it produces the following `.s` file

```
    .file   "test.cpp"
    .option nopic
    .attribute arch, "rv32i2p0_m2p0"
    .attribute unaligned_access, 0
    .attribute stack_align, 16
    .text
    .section    .srodata,"a"
    .align  2
    .type   _ZStL19piecewise_construct, @object
    .size   _ZStL19piecewise_construct, 1
_ZStL19piecewise_construct:
    .zero   1
    .text
    .align  2
    .type   _ZL20__gthread_key_deletei, @function
_ZL20__gthread_key_deletei:
.LFB459:
    .cfi_startproc
    addi    sp,sp,-32
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    sw  s0,28(sp)
    .cfi_offset 8, -4
    addi    s0,sp,32
    .cfi_def_cfa 8, 0
    sw  a0,-20(s0)
    li  a5,0
    mv  a0,a5
    lw  s0,28(sp)
    .cfi_restore 8
    .cfi_def_cfa 2, 32
    addi    sp,sp,32
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
    jr  ra
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE459:
    .size   _ZL20__gthread_key_deletei, .-_ZL20__gthread_key_deletei
    .local  _ZStL8__ioinit
    .comm   _ZStL8__ioinit,1,4
    .section    .rodata
    .align  2
.LC0:
    .string "Hello, world!"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1492:
    .cfi_startproc
    addi    sp,sp,-16
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    sw  ra,12(sp)
    sw  s0,8(sp)
    .cfi_offset 1, -4
    .cfi_offset 8, -8
    addi    s0,sp,16
    .cfi_def_cfa 8, 0
    lui a5,%hi(.LC0)
    addi    a1,a5,%lo(.LC0)
    lui a5,%hi(_ZSt4cout)
    addi    a0,a5,%lo(_ZSt4cout)
    call    _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc
    mv  a4,a0
    lui a5,%hi(_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_)
    addi    a1,a5,%lo(_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_)
    mv  a0,a4
    call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
    li  a5,0
    mv  a0,a5
    lw  ra,12(sp)
    .cfi_restore 1
    lw  s0,8(sp)
    .cfi_restore 8
    .cfi_def_cfa 2, 16
    addi    sp,sp,16
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
    jr  ra
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1492:
    .size   main, .-main
    .align  2
    .type   _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii, @function
_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii:
.LFB1981:
    .cfi_startproc
    addi    sp,sp,-32
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    sw  ra,28(sp)
    sw  s0,24(sp)
    .cfi_offset 1, -4
    .cfi_offset 8, -8
    addi    s0,sp,32
    .cfi_def_cfa 8, 0
    sw  a0,-20(s0)
    sw  a1,-24(s0)
    lw  a4,-20(s0)
    li  a5,1
    bne a4,a5,.L7
    lw  a4,-24(s0)
    li  a5,65536
    addi    a5,a5,-1
    bne a4,a5,.L7
    lui a5,%hi(_ZStL8__ioinit)
    addi    a0,a5,%lo(_ZStL8__ioinit)
    call    _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    lui a5,%hi(__dso_handle)
    addi    a2,a5,%lo(__dso_handle)
    lui a5,%hi(_ZStL8__ioinit)
    addi    a1,a5,%lo(_ZStL8__ioinit)
    lui a5,%hi(_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev)
    addi    a0,a5,%lo(_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev)
    call    __cxa_atexit
.L7:
    nop
    lw  ra,28(sp)
    .cfi_restore 1
    lw  s0,24(sp)
    .cfi_restore 8
    .cfi_def_cfa 2, 32
    addi    sp,sp,32
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
    jr  ra
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1981:
    .size   _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii, .-_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    .align  2
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB1982:
    .cfi_startproc
    addi    sp,sp,-16
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    sw  ra,12(sp)
    sw  s0,8(sp)
    .cfi_offset 1, -4
    .cfi_offset 8, -8
    addi    s0,sp,16
    .cfi_def_cfa 8, 0
    li  a5,65536
    addi    a1,a5,-1
    li  a0,1
    call    _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii
    lw  ra,12(sp)
    .cfi_restore 1
    lw  s0,8(sp)
    .cfi_restore 8
    .cfi_def_cfa 2, 16
    addi    sp,sp,16
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
    jr  ra
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1982:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align  2
    .word   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.2.0"
```

If I try to run this in an RISCV emulator (for example [Jupiter](https://github.com/andrescv/Jupiter) or [BRISC-V](https://ascslab.org/research/briscv/simulator/simulator.html#)), then I doesn't seem to be recognized as valid RISC-V code.

If I try to run with `riscv32-unknown-elf-run`, it runs successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1: Adding error messages**

```
file '(...)/test.s' has errors

Jupiter: (error) asm::2:10: (syntax) unexpected input 'nopic'

 >  .option nopic
            ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::7:11: (syntax) unexpected input '.srodata'

 >  .section .srodata,"a"
             ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::9:8: (syntax) unexpected input '_ZStL19piecewise_construct'

 >  .type _ZStL19piecewise_construct, @object
          ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::12:8: .zero directive can not appear in .text segment

 >  .zero 1
          ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::15:8: (syntax) unexpected input '_ZL20__gthread_key_deletei'

 >  .type _ZL20__gthread_key_deletei, @function
          ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::17:8: invalid language element: ':'

 > .LFB459:
          ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::18:2: invalid directive '.cfi_startproc'

 >  .cfi_startproc
    ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::20:22: (syntax) unexpected input '32'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
                        ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::22:14: (syntax) unexpected input '8'

 >  .cfi_offset 8, -4
                ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::24:15: (syntax) unexpected input '8'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa 8, 0
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::29:15: (syntax) unexpected input '8'

 >  .cfi_restore 8
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::32:22: (syntax) unexpected input '0'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
                        ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::34:2: invalid directive '.cfi_endproc'

 >  .cfi_endproc
    ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::35:8: invalid language element: ':'

 > .LFE459:
          ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::41:5: invalid language element: ':'

 > .LC0:
       ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::46:8: (syntax) unexpected input 'main'

 >  .type main, @function
          ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::48:9: invalid language element: ':'

 > .LFB1492:
           ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::49:2: invalid directive '.cfi_startproc'

 >  .cfi_startproc
    ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::51:22: (syntax) unexpected input '16'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
                        ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::54:14: (syntax) unexpected input '1'

 >  .cfi_offset 1, -4
                ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::57:15: (syntax) unexpected input '8'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa 8, 0
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::58:13: (syntax) unexpected input '.LC0'

 >  lui a5,%hi(.LC0)
               ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::59:17: (syntax) unexpected input '.LC0'

 >  addi a1,a5,%lo(.LC0)
                   ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::71:15: (syntax) unexpected input '1'

 >  .cfi_restore 1
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::73:15: (syntax) unexpected input '8'

 >  .cfi_restore 8
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::76:22: (syntax) unexpected input '0'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
                        ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::78:2: invalid directive '.cfi_endproc'

 >  .cfi_endproc
    ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::79:9: invalid language element: ':'

 > .LFE1492:
           ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::82:8: (syntax) unexpected input '_Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii'

 >  .type _Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii, @function
          ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::84:9: invalid language element: ':'

 > .LFB1981:
           ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::85:2: invalid directive '.cfi_startproc'

 >  .cfi_startproc
    ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::87:22: (syntax) unexpected input '32'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
                        ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::90:14: (syntax) unexpected input '1'

 >  .cfi_offset 1, -4
                ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::93:15: (syntax) unexpected input '8'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa 8, 0
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::98:12: (syntax) unexpected input '.L7'

 >  bne a4,a5,.L7
              ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::102:12: (syntax) unexpected input '.L7'

 >  bne a4,a5,.L7
              ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::113:4: invalid language element: ':'

 > .L7:
      ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::116:15: (syntax) unexpected input '1'

 >  .cfi_restore 1
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::118:15: (syntax) unexpected input '8'

 >  .cfi_restore 8
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::121:22: (syntax) unexpected input '0'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
                        ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::123:2: invalid directive '.cfi_endproc'

 >  .cfi_endproc
    ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::124:9: invalid language element: ':'

 > .LFE1981:
           ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::127:8: (syntax) unexpected input '_GLOBAL__sub_I_main'

 >  .type _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, @function
          ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::129:9: invalid language element: ':'

 > .LFB1982:
           ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::130:2: invalid directive '.cfi_startproc'

 >  .cfi_startproc
    ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::132:22: (syntax) unexpected input '16'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
                        ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::135:14: (syntax) unexpected input '1'

 >  .cfi_offset 1, -4
                ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::138:15: (syntax) unexpected input '8'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa 8, 0
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::144:15: (syntax) unexpected input '1'

 >  .cfi_restore 1
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::146:15: (syntax) unexpected input '8'

 >  .cfi_restore 8
                 ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::149:22: (syntax) unexpected input '0'

 >  .cfi_def_cfa_offset 0
                        ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::151:2: invalid directive '.cfi_endproc'

 >  .cfi_endproc
    ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::152:9: invalid language element: ':'

 > .LFE1982:
           ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::156:2: .word directive can not appear in .text segment

 >  .word _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    ^

Jupiter: (error) asm::157:10: (syntax) unexpected input '__dso_handle'

 >  .hidden __dso_handle
            ^

Jupiter: (error) simulation halted due to assembly errors
```

Comment: it seems that the translators are different but I am not familiar with jupiter and brisc-v to be exact

Comment: can you post error messages?

Comment: I added the error messages (there are a lot) from the Jupiter simulator.

Comment: Please do not use code snippet tags for things that are not Javascript.

Comment: It was the easiest way for me to show the entire code snippet without having to indent every line because copy-pasting into the text view is very cumbersome. But thanks for fixing it :-)

Comment: @memosdp: Did you figure out anything? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you are doing wrong is that you are using two different assemblers. The `g++` tool-chain uses `gas` which uses at most `AT&T` syntax and the `Jupiter` on which I am not familiar to help with, uses another syntax.

If there is any compatibility bridge between them, then this is the only way you can follow. If there is no compatibility then you have to choose side.

If you choose `g++` aka `Gnu Compiler Collection` then there is an emulator to work with, [`Qemu`](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Platforms/RISCV).

If you choose `Jupiter`, I think you have to write in assembly with the `Jupiter`'s syntax.

Comment: Oh, I see – thank you very much for pointing that out! I will setup and try out Qemu and report back. If all goes well I'll accept you answer :-)

Comment: I'm running `qemu-system-riscv32 -kernel test` (`test` is the executable). After this a black terminal with the prompt `(qemu)`, though I'm unsure how to actually verify the execution of the file. What should I do? I looked at the [monitor docs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor), but couldn't deduce what to do.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll make this work eventually. Now I know that I'm on the correct track. Thanks :-)